# Hyphens (dashes) in resx resource file not rendering IE7/8

Tags: asp.net, html, internet-explorer, localization, resx

I'm working on an MVC project which uses localisation via resource files, all other foreign characters seem to render no problem in Internet Explorer 7 & 8, except for hyphens.

It just displays a space where the hyphen should be.  I've tried putting the ascii code `&#45;` but this doesn't work.

[image: Screenshot of the problem]

Any help would be great, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've figured out this was down to the font being used on the site, "Lucida Grande", even though this was being imported with @font-face it didn't like the hyphens!

Changing the font to Trebuchet MS in my conditional stylesheet fixed the problem.  Hopefully this is helpful to anybody else having a similar problem